# How to calculate initial Elo rating?

Tags: rating, elo

I completed my first FIDE rated tournament with 0.5/3 points against Elo rated players. This weekend I'm going to another tournament, where I'll probably meet other 2 Elo rated opponents, completing the necessary condition for the first official Elo rating calculation.
Using the FIDE simulator (https://ratings.fide.com/calculator_rp.phtml) it seems that even if I lose I'll get the initial Elo rating of 1440. Is that correct?

On the other hand my national rating will be certainly less than that so what happens at that point: the national rating will be lifted up to the FIDE rating or the other way around?

P.S. I play in Italy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer your question about Italian rating, but I'm nearly sure that your national rating won't go up. They (FIDE and national) are separate rating systems and they shouldn't affect each other.

About the FIDE rating, it is regulated at http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=172&view=article `FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 July 2014`. At article 8.2 you can check the exact formula.

```
8.2 Determining the Rating 'Ru' in a given event of a previously unrated player.
    8.21 If an unrated player scores zero in his first rated event, his score is disregarded.
    First determine the average rating of his competition 'Rc'.
    (a) In a Swiss or Team tournament: this is simply the average rating of his rated opponents.
    (b) The results of both rated and unrated players in a round-robin tournament are taken into account. For unrated players, the average rating of the competition 'Rc' is also the tournament average 'Ra' determined as follows:
        (i) Determine the average rating of the rated players 'Rar'.
        (ii) Determine p for each of the rated players against all their opponents.
        Then determine dp for each of these players. 
        Then determine the average of these dp = 'dpa'.
        (iii) 'n' is the number of opponents.
        Ra = Rar - dpa x n/(n+1)
    8.22 If he scores 50%, then Ru = Ra
    8.23 If he scores more than 50%, then Ru = Ra + 20 for each half point scored over 50%
    8.24 If he scores less than 50% in a Swiss or team tournament:  Ru = Rc + dp
    8.25 If he scores less than 50% in a round-robin: Ru = Ra + dp x n/(n+1).
```

So, more or less, your initial rating will be your performance in your first tournament(s).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the calculator you linked, the initial rating (and in fact every rating change later) depends on the Elo of your opponents. So if you already know the Elo of your opponents this weekend and you calculated the average rating of all your rated opponents correctly and for 0.5/5 the calculator returns 1440, then that's what you'll get.

The national rating is completely independent of the Elo rating.

Answer (score 1):

I play in Italy too. After you gain a FIDE rating you will **always** play using it. Italian Elo will disappear. Your new Elo will be the FIDE Elo, no adjustments.
When playing against Italian Elo your FIDE Elo will not change, while when playing against FIDE rated opponents, of course the Elo will change.